# How do i display my images 20(pixels or %) CUT from below so that the full picture is not displayed

Tags: html, css

Assume the original picture is 500px in height,400 px in width .I want to display this picture in website such that only 480px in visible in height. is this possible using css? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you don't know the height of the image, and you need to cut the image, then you can use the negative margin and `overflow: hidden`. Check out my answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To crop, you could try using an outer `<div>` with `overflow: hidden` and the resulting set width and height, have the image within it, then use margins to crop. The margin value would be the difference of the original height and the cropped height, so in your case 20px.

http://jsfiddle.net/DjyzK/1/

I added a border to the DIV so you could see where it lies.

The absolute positioning is there simply so you can see it when it's not hugging the edges of the page.

If you don't know the height/width of the image, try this fork of Praveen's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xULaP/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the height of the image, and you need to cut the image, then you can use the negative margin and `overflow: hidden` (Left is the image as is, and the right one is cropped one):

### HTML

```
<div class="crop">
    <span><img src="http://images.gizmag.com/hero/windows8leak.jpg" /></span>
    <strong><img src="http://images.gizmag.com/hero/windows8leak.jpg" /></strong>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.crop {overflow: hidden;}
.crop strong {display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: -50px;}
.crop strong img {display: block; margin-bottom: -20px;}​
```

### Demo

[image: Cropped Image using CSS]

Check out the demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/xULaP/

Comment: He only needs one image, and you only need one margin. My fork: http://jsfiddle.net/xULaP/1/

Comment: @MusikAnimal, I just showed the original and cropped versions for comparison, side by side, FYI!!!

Comment: Nah I figured, just was a little confusing for me given the positioning

Comment: Also the `<strong>` tag is only valid with normal character data within it. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/strong.html

Answer (score 0):

Yup: set the image as the background of an element, and specify that element’s width and height. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p7UAy/)

Comment: Seems like the easier solution, and here you could use `background-position` to set what part of the image is to be cropped.